# What's the difference between this topic and the English for Language Learners Topic?

Tags: discussion

See title.
I must have at least 30 character in the body to post a question.

Comment: This topic is recursive. I don't know about the ELL topic because you didn't identify it.

Comment: What's the question? Why does it belong here (on Meta)? We don't really care what's on-topic on other sites (although we give hints to them sometimes).

Comment: @jlawler Presumably a back-formation from "on-topic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site is about the study of *language*, as a whole. The goal is to better understand how language works and how it changes.

English Language Learners is about gaining proficiency in English. The goal is to speak English more fluently.

There can be some overlap, but the goals tend to differ.

Comment: becoming proficient in English. :)